# Configure gradle to use local maven repository by default for all builds

Tags: gradle

Can I configure gradle to use my local maven repository *by default for all builds?* It'd be nice to not have to download every dependency already there and also be nice to not have to put the below snippet into every `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Also, is there a way to have gradle put its dependencies in the local maven repository instead of the local gradle cache? Or are they incompatible/there is not way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you have to look at the [init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) for gradle to configure all your builds. You are able to provide there something like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

To configure repositories for all the projects. Due to documentation, you are able to put the init script under `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory to apply it to all your builds.

But I'm not sure, whether it's possible to disable local gradle cache at all. It seems possible to publish your artifacts into the local maven repo, but not it's dependencies.

Comment: I did as you said, create `init.gradle`  under my gradle local installation `D:/gradle-5.2.1/init.d/`, my `init.gradle` looks like `allprojects {repositories{maven(url "my company nexus repository")}}`. However, every I create a gradle java project, the repository still is `jcenter()`, what I missed?